# SELECT using file data won't work

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdo

I have a query that returns nothing when it calls array data from files, but works fine if I declare the arrays inline.

Here's what's NOT working:

```
<?php

$firstnames = file("firstnames.txt");
$lastnames  = file("lastnames.txt");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($firstnames); $i++) {
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT P_ID FROM personal WHERE personal.FirstName=:firstname AND personal.LastName=:lastname");

    $stmt1->bindParam(':firstname', $firstnames[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':lastname', $lastnames[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt1->execute();
    $row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($row) {
        foreach ($row as $key) {
            $PIDs[] = $key;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

But if I **replace the the first two lines** above with this, it works:

```
$firstnames = array("Michaela","Noeleen","Anton","Gerard","Gerard","Billy");
$lastnames = array("Daly","O'Brien","Vidal","Boyle","Espital","Mason");
```

I can output the `$firstnames` and `$lastnames` **file contents to screen**, so the file data is available to the query within the script. Any ideas what might be wrong?
File data is as follows, firstnames.txt :

```
Philip
Anne
Derek
Fíona
Katelyn
Margaret
```

Last names same format. No commas.

Comment: Yes! the contents of the file which you haven't actually shown

Comment: are you getting proper data in $firstnames while reading from file

Comment: You should `prepare` the statement once, outside the loop and execute multiple times within the loop.

Comment: Yes, @Ahmed Ginani the data in the files is fine. This works: 
$lastnames = file("lastnames.txt");
for ($i=0; $i<=count($lastnames); $i++)
 { echo $lastnames[$i]; 
   echo "<br>"; 
 }

Comment: @Hego you may need to include a small representation of those files and if they're on separate lines and how they're formatted.

Comment: I suppose that names in the database do not contain *line feed characters*

Comment: @Fred -ii- I've done that now.

Comment: @Hego Thanks. Are you getting any output? I don't see you echoing anything, I only see a `$PIDs[] = $key;` declaration. any errors also http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php ? or with php's error reporting.

Comment: No, @Your Common Sense. I just copy .xls columns and dump them into a .txt file. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Fred Yes, I can echo. This works: 

$lastnames = file("lastnames.txt"); for ($i=0; $i<=count($lastnames); $i++) { echo $lastnames[$i]; echo "<br>"; }

Comment: YES this is exact problem. Do you understand what a line feed character is?

Comment: @Your Common Sense. Tells computer that EOL has been reached? e.g. \n ?

Comment: if on Windows `"\r\n"` if on \*NIX `"\n"` and cross platform `PHP_EOL`. Double quotes are important.

Comment: @Fred Thanks. But what do I do? Do I remove or add these? In my files or in my php script? I'm a newbie at this.

Comment: Think I've got it:  $lastnames = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $lastnames);